# Rails ExceptionNotifier -> Notifier based on title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-middleware, exception-notification

Is it possible to change ExceptionNotifier exception_recipients based on some variable or maybe Exception title?

I want to send some main notifies to one email and other created via ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception to another.

Comment: You just write your own [custom notifier](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/master/docs/notifiers/custom.md#custom-notifier) that does whatever you want.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to choose which notifier is used or always all are used and inside custom one I must put code to send or not send based on my own logic?